# How to fix inconsistent number of rows in Unity-2D

Tags: unity-2d, workspaces

In Unity-2D, I only have one row of workspaces when I switch with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd>, but two when I hit <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>. Is there a way I can get two rows in both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a know issue that was fixed a few days ago, but it looks like we will have to wait until 12.04 to see if fixed by default.

Here is the bug report page:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity-2d/+bug/715587

On the upside, on that page this comment ( https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity-2d/+bug/715587/comments/9 ) gives a python script that will resolve the issue in your current session.  What I did was put that script in ~/bin, make it executable, and then add it to Startup Applications.  This will fix up your workspace issue on login, so if you changes your workspace layout you will need to run the script again (say by logging out then back in, or just run it in a terminal).